# Insert png icon and text in a field

Tags: magento-1.9, php, css, phtml

I have installed in my Magento an [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advance-newsletter-pop-up-by-oscprofessionals.html) to show a popup newsletter. This extension has a normal field for inserting email. Now I want to insert in the field a icon image (message icon) + a text. I tried to insert  this code, but it  created a problem:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('http://mydomain444.com/icon.png') ?>" alt="" />
```

It's  probably wrong position.

This is a code in subscribe.phtml:

```
<?php
/**
 * @category    Oscprofessional
 * @package     Oscprofessional_AdvancedNewsletter
 * @author      Oscprofessionals Team <standard@oscprofessionals.com>
 */
?>
<div class="newsletter-title">
    <div class="news-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('New discoveries every week straight to your inbox.') ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="news-title-new">
        <span><?php echo Mage::helper('oscpadvancednewsletter')->getPopupFormTitle(); ?></span>
        <span><?php echo Mage::helper('oscpadvancednewsletter')->getPopupDescription(); ?><span>
    </div>
    <div class="close">
        <a id="cancel-filters-btn" style="display: inline;"><?php echo $this->__('Close') ?></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-subscribe-header">
    <div class="news-bg">
        <div id="newsletter-msg" style="display: none;">
            <span id="newsletter-msg-txt"></span>
            <div id="close-button">
                <a id="cancel-filters-btn" class="button subart" style="display: block;"><?php echo $this->__('Close') ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail-popup">
            <input type="hidden" name="ajaxAction" value="1" />
            <label class="news-art-label"><?php echo $this->__('Receive updates on the latest additions and exclusive stories') ?></label>
            <div class="form-subscribe">
                <div id="inpbox" class="input-button">
                    <div class="v-fix"><input name="email" type="text" id="newsletter" value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter your email address here') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" /></div>
                    <button type="submit" class="button subart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Join Now') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Join Now') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery("#newsletter-validate-detail-popup .v-fix #newsletter").click(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == 'Enter your email address here')
        {
            jQuery(this).val('');
        }
    });

    jQuery("#newsletter-validate-detail-popup .v-fix #newsletter").blur(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == '')
        {
            jQuery(this).val('Enter your email address here');
        }
    });

    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new Validation($('newsletter-validate-detail-popup'), {
        onFormValidate: function(result, form) {
            if (result) {
                var newsletterSubscriberFormDetailAjax = new Ajax.Updater(
                        {
                        },
                        "<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>",
                        {
                            asynchronous: true,
                            evalScripts: false,
                            onComplete: function(request, json) {

                                $('newsletter-validate-detail-popup').hide();
                                $('newsletter-msg').show()
                            },
                            onSuccess: function(response) {
                                var json = response.responseText.evalJSON();                
                                if (json.success == 'true') {
                                    $('newsletter-validate-detail-popup').hide();
                                    $('close-button').show();
                                    $('newsletter-msg-txt').update(json.msg);
                                    $('newsletter-msg-txt').removeClassName('error-msg');
                                    $('newsletter-msg-txt').addClassName('success-msg');
                                    $('newsletter-msg').show();
                                    closePopup()
                                    $('newsletter-form-again').show();
                                    $('newsletter-form-again').stopObserving();
                                    $('newsletter-form-again').observe('click', function() {
                                        $('newsletter-validate-detail-popup').reset();
                                        $('newsletter-validate-detail-popup').show();
                                        $('newsletter-msg').hide();
                                    });                                 

                                } else {
                                    $('newsletter-validate-detail-popup').show();
                                    $('newsletter-msg-txt').update(json.msg);
                                    $('newsletter-msg-txt').addClassName('error-msg');
                                    $('inpbox').addClassName('error-failed');
                                    $('newsletter-msg-txt').removeClassName('success-msg');
                                    $('newsletter-msg').show();
                                    $('close-button').hide();
                                    $('newsletter-form-again').hide();
                                }
                            },
                            onLoading: function(request, json) {
                            },
                            parameters: $('newsletter-validate-detail-popup').serialize(this)
                        }
                );
            } else {
                jQuery('.validation-failed').each(function() {

                    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('validation-failed-label');
                    jQuery('.subscribe-content').addClass('validation-failed-div');
                });
            }
        },
        addClassNameToContainer: true
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if (jQuery('a#link_button').length == 1) {
            jQuery('a#link_button').fancybox({
                'onStart': function() {
                    jQuery("#fancybox-overlay").css({"position": "fixed"});
                }
            });
            jQuery('#subscribe_popups').find('form').eq(0).submit(function() {
                return false;
            });
            jQuery('a#link_button').click();
        }
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#cancel-filters-btn', function() {
        jQuery.fancybox.close();
    });

    function closePopup() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery.fancybox.close();
        }, 5000)
    }

</script>
```

i tried to insert the code in :

```
<div id="inpbox" class="input-button">
                    <div class="v-fix"><input name="email" type="text" id="newsletter" value="  **<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('http://mydomain444.com/icon.png') ?>" alt="" />**<?php echo $this->__('Enter your email address here') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" /></div>
                    <button type="submit" class="button subart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Join Now') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Join Now') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>
```

How can I solve this, to have the result identical to this image?

[image: wanted]

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to insert the image directly into the text input, but rather have it as a placeholder. This uses the `placeholder=`tag for the text, which is not supported in older browsers.

**PHTML**

```
<input name="email" type="text" id="newsletter" value="" 
alt="<?php echo $this->__('Enter your email address here') ?>" 
placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter your email address here') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    #newsletter {
        background:url("http://mydomain444.com/icon.png") no-repeat;
    }
    #newsletter:focus{
        background:none;
    }
</style>
```

Your image tag is incorrect, you are using a full url inside of `$this->getSkinUrl`, which should actually have the file name you are trying to pull.

i.e. `<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/icon.png') ?>`

If you needed the background image to be set dynamically, you could put the css snippet into the template and use the `getSkinUrl`call, but if not it would be best to keep the css in your custom.css (name is up to you) file.

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19244746/2813046